# how to left join mysql in crystal reports?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

i tried to create a left join on my crystal reports using mysql in vb.net. but it seems that i dont have output on my reports.does anyone know how to use left join in crystal reports in vb.net? please help. thank you guys!

```
HERE IS MY CODE SIR..

Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Public Class historyrep
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim p(7) As MySqlParameter
Private Sub historyrep_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String


    sql = "SELECT complaint.*,solution.* FROM complaint LEFT JOIN solution ON complaint.tran_no=solution.tran_no WHERE complaint.status='finished'"
    Dim dscmd As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionsrvr)

    dscmd.Fill(ds, "complaint")
    connectionsrvr.Close()

    Dim objret As New CrystalReport1
    objret.setdatasource(ds.Tables(0))

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objret
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Perhaps there are no rows in `complaint` where `complaint.status='finished'`.

Comment: there is rows in complaint sir. specially in status.

Comment: The first thing that struck me is that you're getting all fields from each table. Are there fields in both tables that have the same name? Next, you're giving your table a specific name, but then referencing a table by index. Your query appears to return one table of results, so referencing by zero index should be fine, but what happens when you reference by the name you give it? Do you have some kind of profiler to tell you whether the command is executing correctly on the database server?

Comment: okay sir. ill try call each columnnames in tables :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your syntax is correct, so I would try a `Left Outer Join`, which works for some databases. Also, for troubleshooting purposes, leave the `Where`  clause out to make sure you get every record possible. 
In situations like these where the syntax is correct you have to start from the broadest SELECT statement and then start refining until you find the problem.
Another thing I noticed is that you never open your `connectionsrvr`.

Comment: i arleady open the connectionsrvr to the module i called sir

Answer (score 0):

1. Attempt the query by itself in mysql workbench or similar

   ```
   SELECT complaint.*,
          solution.*
   FROM   complaint
      LEFT JOIN solution
                 ON complaint.tran_no = solution.tran_no
   WHERE  complaint.status = 'finished'
   ```
2. If it succeeds with the expected result set, and you have access to Crystal Reports designer, try the same query as a command table there.
3. If that succeeds with the expected result set, then the issue is somewhere in the VB code or API integration. Check all event logs for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an ODBC connection with your SQL custom query , and create a command in Crystal Reports without a dataset. I am using MySQL driver ODBC 6.8, CR 13 and .NET 4.5

```
Select `table2`.* ,`table1`.* from 
 FROM   `table1`
join    `table2` on 
 `table1`.`Cod_P` =  `table2`.`Cod_Prop`
where  1=1
```

[Source Mysql.org](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-crystalreports.html)

Comment: Why did you use two "FROM" ? And why `WHERE 1=1` ? Remove it or use `WHERE 1`.